# Change embedded youtube address in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, youtube

I have an app that I'm trying to allow users to choose which youTube movie they play. I have a UIWebView with an embedded url, but I want that embedded code to able to change.

So far, I can't get this to change. This current setup only shows a blank white screen. When I put youtubeURL in place of the @ it works fine, but not changeable. Any ideas how to change the URL? I have it setup so they can type a url that gets saved as youtubeURL, and that is the URL I want the UIWebView to show.

In my viewDidLoad:

```
youtubeURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQ7R_buZPSo";
```

In my playMovie triggered by a button:

```
 NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                      <html><head>\
                      </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                      <embed id=\"yt\" src=\" %@ \" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"\
                      width=\"1024\" height=\"748\"></embed>\
                      </body></html>", youtubeURL];

    [self.view addSubview:youTubeView];
    [youTubeView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
        ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean? what you want isn't exactly clear. do you want users to input their own youtube link, or do you want to prepopulate an array of links to use? be more specific please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this started working randomly. I understand the fact that the user can't change the code, which is why I had youtubeURL to allow them to change the youtube link. I just had them type whatever they wanted into a UITextField, and saved it to a label as well as to youtubeURL. Works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to have an input text box and then do `youtubeURL = inputLabel.text` (or just skip the youtubeURL variable altogether.

You can't have the user change the code.